# gitlab pipeline failed to run

Tags: gitlab-ce, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-ci-trigger

I am trying to add commit task in the gitlab
It basically it executes a ansible playbook  on load balancers.

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  
  script:

    - export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=./loadbalancers/ansible.cfg

    - ansible-playbook -i ./loadbalancers/inventory.yml ./loadbalancers/show-runconfig.yml

    - cd /repositories/network-management/loadbalancers/backup_configs
    - git config --global user.name "user"
    - git config --global user.email "user@domain.com"
    - CI_REPOSITORY_URL https://gitlab-ci-token:glpat-xfdsfdsfadah@gitlabcom/ops/network-management.git/
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "Update A10 Load Balancer configurations"
    - git push origin main
```

thats how pipeline looks like. but when it commit it in the project repository root.
I can see error message in the pipelines saying:

remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.blacksunplc.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.blacksunplc.com/ops/network-management.git/'